# Nodejs npm install sqlite3 and other database package error

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, npm

I am trying install sqlite3 with npm but i am getting error.
Also when i was trying install about database packages, i am getting error. I tried install sqlite3, better-sqlite3 and quick.db and i got error. But other package didn't get error. I am getting error only about database packages.

I am running this command:
`npm i sqlite3`
and i am getting this error.

```
> sqlite3@5.0.1 install E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1342) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "E:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=E:\\Belgelerim\\Projects\\Discord Bots\\Muthis_Js_Botu\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=E:\\Belgelerim\\Projects\\Discord Bots\\Muthis_Js_Botu\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6" "--python=C:\\Users\\User\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'E:\nodejs\node.exe E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6 --python=C:\Users\User\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "E:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Belgelerim\\Projects\\Discord Bots\\Muthis_Js_Botu\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'E:\nodejs\node.exe E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6 --python=C:\Users\User\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe' (1)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Belgelerim\Projects\Discord Bots\Muthis_Js_Botu\package.json'
npm WARN Muthis_Js_Botu No description
npm WARN Muthis_Js_Botu No repository field.
npm WARN Muthis_Js_Botu No README data
npm WARN Muthis_Js_Botu No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-03T13_40_13_314Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you read the messages?  It tells you exactly what’s wrong.

```
yp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
```

Comment: yes, i read those

i have python 3.8.3
i have visual studio 2017 community editiyon and C++ build tools

but i am getting this error